# Funciones Asíncronas en Angular 2+

Tags: angular, webservice, typescript, funciones, asincronismo

Tengo un servicio que me trae la siguiente información:

```
[{"id_device_pk":231,"device_name":"smart1","humidity":81,"temperature":28,"light":18,"date":"2019-07-14","time":"22:58:42"}]
```

En `services/device.service.ts` estoy consumiendo el servicio de está manera:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as ROUTE from '@services/route.ts';

@Injectable()

export class DeviceService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getDevice(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(ROUTE.BASE_API + ROUTE.DEVICE);
  }
}
```

En el componente `device.component.ts` estoy llamando al servicio de la siguiente forma:

```
public getDevice(): void {
    this._deviceService.getDevice().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.devices = result;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      },
    )
  }
```

Necesito que cada vez que el servicio genere nueva información (aproximadamente los valores cambian cada 30 seg), se visualicen los cambios de forma automática en el Front.

He intentado realizando está función de JavaScript pero no es compatible:

```
setTimeout('getDevice()',10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

has trabajado con `rxjs`? tu problema lo puedes resolver con `Subject`, es más fácil de lo que parece

En `DeviceService` agrega un nuevo Subject y subscríbete a la respuesta, cuando obtengas un valor se lo pasa al `next` del Subject

```
export class DeviceService {

  public mySubject = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getDevice() {
    this._http.get(ROUTE.BASE_API + ROUTE.DEVICE)
      .subscribe((response) => {

          this.mySubject.next(response);

      })
  }
}
```

Ahora en el `NgOnInit` de tu `device.component` utiliza un setInterval para llamar al método del servicio cada cierto tiempo y subscríbete a `mySubject`, este se encargará de escuchar cada vez que hay un cambio, ahora cruza los dedos y si todo ha ido bien, en ese `console.log` verás los datos

```
ngOnInit () {
    setInterval(() => {
      this._deviceService.getDevice()
    }, 1000)

    this._deviceService.mySubject
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

Saludos